# Techniques under the influence of pepper spray / temporarily blinded

Tags: self-defense, technique

Suppose you are attacked by an attacker using pepper spray and you experience the effects such as shortness of breath and involuntary closing of the eyes. You are in a remote location, so no help is available and you have no weapons.  Suppose the attacker is after you for your purse. How would you defend yourself from being robbed. Remember you are temporarily blinded, so you can't run away.

Comment: I can't see this question spawning anything more than speculation and choreographed fight sequences.

Comment: @coinbird [This was discussed on meta before](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/82)

Comment: @Sardathrion I know, I'm just a pessimist :)

Comment: As framed, this is a bad question which basically boils down to: "With nearly everything stacked against you, what magical solution can you come up with?".  A better question might be, "What techniques and tactics are best suited when impaired by pepper spray?"  Please tell us more why you're asking this question and maybe people can point you to better things for protecting yourself and/or finding information that can help you.

Comment: @Bankuei That is what the question was before I said that it would be massively over broad because there would be too many factors to consider from one attacker to an army of riot police hell bend on smashing resistance and a multitude of weapons possible. ⍨

Comment: Eh.  Right now it reads equivalent to that question we had a while back "5 guys attack you in an alley and you can't get away".  Strangely specific while eliminating nearly every useful thing you would do (run, use a makeshift weapon), leaving... a non-described environment? I want the poster to give us a better understanding of why this is being asked to better frame it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid my answer isn't going to be very positive in this case.

The truth is, taken by surprise, fights are hard enough to win when you both are equal sized and equal abled. When you are also the weaker one (a purse usually indicates a female, and I would guess your attacker is a bigger male), the odds of getting out of it unharmed decrease considerably.

Now to make things worse, you're pepper sprayed so you can't see and can hardly breathe. And there's nobody else around to help or even hear you scream.

In that situation, you would need a miracle to get you out unharmed.

The one saving grace here is that you indicated the attacker is after your purse. In that case, you give it to him. And do so as quickly as you can. Tell him he can have it. Then toss it far away from you and run in the opposite direction. That will buy you some time. And scream as loud as you can as you run. Even if you can't see very well, it's better than nothing.

That's all you can possibly do in that situation to save your life.

The problem with that is that you're going to be taken completely by surprise. You're not going to remember what to do. The shock of getting pepper sprayed will put you in a panicked state for a while. And if your attacker is after your purse, there won't be any time to gather your wits and throw your purse away. He'll have already grabbed it and will be making his exit very quickly. That is, if he was only after your purse.

It's really bad news if he wasn't just after your purse.

Assuming the attacker continues to attack you even after you've given him your purse, are there martial arts that can help you in these situations? Sort of. I would say Brazilian Jiujitsu is going to be your best bet. Grappling arts like BJJ have a track record of being successful for women in rape attempts. They can work even with little or no ability to see an opponent.

But even if you're a black belt in BJJ, your odds are still pretty slim in these situations, because you're going to be panicking. Not to mention the body size difference and the possibility that your attacker has a knife or a gun.

Aside from BJJ, the only other martial arts I could recommend would be those like Silat or Kali/Escrima, but only if you have a knife stashed on your person somewhere. Those styles work well when you have a knife.

A handgun is another possibility. Trouble is, women tend to put their guns in their purses, and since the purse is the first thing that will be taken, so too will your gun. So you'd have to wear it in a shoulder holster or something. And there's a chance it will be confiscated by the attacker and used against you if he sees it.

The moral of the story is this: Be aware of your surroundings. And don't make yourself out to be an easy target.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I *cannot* stress this enough:

## ***There should not be anything in your wallet/purse that you cannot easily replace.***

Wallets/purses *should not* contain anything that you think is worth getting injured over. If you have, *take those items out **now** and put them somewhere safe.* Losing your wallet/purse should be all resolved within an hour or so with access to phone and/or computer.

If someone threatens you with weapons: *give them your wallet/purse and run towards safety.* Your life *is not* worth spare change and a few credit cards. Do not let your [pride](http://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/pride.html) get in the way.

If someone injures you with a weapon, you are in big big trouble. In case of a mugging, dump all your valuables away from you and move in the opposite direction as best as you can. In case of a murder attempt… Well, your chances of survival are grim. In any case, you might reflect on the [unwise decisions that lead you to show up there](http://www.nononsenseselfdefense.com/crime_is_a_process.htm).

In muggings, it is rare that weapons are used beyond the threat of use. Injuring or killing someone with a weapon leads to a much stronger police response than just a mugging. However, provoking or bluffing with an attacker is not a sane thing to do. It is about risk vs rewards for the criminal. In addition, your chances of being mugged are probably much less than you think: The [BBC has a crime calculator](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-41178903) if you were in the UK… There are similar data in your local.